# How to avoid warnings in Perl regex substitution with alternatives?

Tags: regex, perl, warnings, substitution

I have this regex.

```
$string =~ s/(?<!["\w])(\w+)(?=:)|(?<=:)([\w\d\\.+=\/]+)/"$1$2"/g;
```

The regex itself works fine.

But since I am am substituting alternatives (and globally), I always get warning that $1 or $2 is uninitialized. These warnings clutter my logfile.

What can I do better to avoid such warning?
Or is my best option to just turn the warning off? I doubt this.

*Side question: Is there possibly some better way of doing this, e.g. not using regex at all?
What I am doing is fixing JSON where some key:value pairs do not have double quotes and JSON module does not like it when trying to decode.*

Comment: What if you replace `$1$2` with `$&`? BTW, your current pattern is invalid.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yep, I just fixed the typo in regex, thanks for noticing. `$&` seems promising (I mean, definitely better than what I have now). Will using it produce warning if neither alternative is matched? If it does, any idea how to avoid that?

Comment: `$&` is the whole match placeholder, and if you use it, remove all capturing groups as they become redundant (`s/(?<!["\w])\w+(?=:)|(?<=:)[\w\\.+=\/]+/"$&"/g`). If you need to use `$1`, use `s/(?|(?<!["\w])(\w+)(?=:)|(?<=:)([\w\\.+=\/]+))/"$1"/g`

Comment: Since it's not actually a problem that $1 or $2 is undefined (the warning is unfortunately misworded) and results in the empty string, you can also disable that warning in the lexical scope where you run that regex. `{ no warnings 'uninitialized'; $string =~ ...; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches to get around this.

If you intend to use capture groups:

- When capturing the entirety of each clause of the alternation.
  Combine the capture groups into 1 and move the group out.

  ```
   (                             # (1 start)
        (?<! ["\w] )
        \w+ 
        (?= : )
     |  
        (?<= : )
        [\w\d\\.+=/]+ 
   )                             # (1 end)
  ```

  `s/((?<!["\w])\w+(?=:)|(?<=:)[\w\d\\.+=\/]+)/"$1"/g`
- Use a *Branch Reset* construct `(?| aaa )`.
  This will cause capture groups in each alternation to start numbering it's groups
  from the same point.

  ```
   (?|
        (?<! ["\w] )
        ( \w+ )                       # (1)
        (?= : )
     |  
        (?<= : )
        ( [\w\d\\.+=/]+ )             # (1)
   )
  ```

  `s/(?|(?<!["\w])(\w+)(?=:)|(?<=:)([\w\d\\.+=\/]+))/"$1"/g`
- Use *Named* capture groups that are re-useable (Similar to a branch reset).
  In each alternation, reuse the same names. Make the group that isn't relevant, the empty group.
  This works by using the *name* in the substitution instead of the number.

  ```
      (?<! ["\w] )
      (?<V1> \w+ )                  # (1)
      (?<V2> )                      # (2)
      (?= : )
   |  
      (?<= : )
      (?<V1> )                      # (3)
      (?<V2> [\w\d\\.+=/]+ )        # (4)
  ```

  `s/(?<!["\w])(?<V1>\w+)(?<V2>)(?=:)|(?<=:)(?<V1>)(?<V2>[\w\d\\.+=\/]+)/"$+{V1}$+{V2}"/g`

---

The two concepts of the named substitution and a branch reset can be combined
if an alternation contains more than 1 capture group.
The example below uses the capture group numbers.

The theory is that you put *dummy* capture groups in each alternation to
"pad" the branch  to equal the largest number of groups in a single alternation.

Indeed, this *must* be done to avoid the bug in Perl regex that could cause a crash.

```
 (?|                    # Branch Reset
                             # ------ Br 1 --------
      ( )                    # (1)
      ( \d{4} )              # (2)
      ABC294
      ( [a-f]+ )             # (3)
   |  
                             # ------ Br 2 --------          
      ( :: )                 # (1)
      ( \d+ )                # (2)
      ABC555
      ( )                    # (3)
   |  
                             # ------ Br 3 --------
      ( == )                 # (1)
      ( )                    # (2)
      ABC18888
      ( )                    # (3)
 )
```

`s/(?|()(\d{4})ABC294([a-f]+)|(::)(\d+)ABC555()|(==)()ABC18888())/"$1$2$3"/g`

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Cpanel::JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cpanel::JSON::XS)'s [relaxed mode](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cpanel::JSON::XS#$json-=-$json-%3Erelaxed-([$enable])), or [JSONY](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSONY), to parse the almost-JSON and then write out regular JSON using Cpanel::JSON::XS. Depending what exactly is wrong with your input data one or the other might understand it better.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cpanel::JSON::XS 'encode_json';

# JSON is normally UTF-8 encoded; if you're reading it from a file, you will likely need to decode it from UTF-8
my $string = q<{foo: 1,bar:'baz',}>;

my $data = Cpanel::JSON::XS->new->relaxed->decode($string);
my $json = encode_json $data;
print "$json\n";

use JSONY;
my $data = JSONY->new->load($string);
my $json = encode_json $data;
print "$json\n";
```